# How do I make each instance have a random seed for a procedural building

Tags: procedural, instances, geometry-nodes

I've designed a procedural building but I can't distribute them on instances with each of them having a random seed. [image]

Answer (score 0):

**Indeed, you can't.**

Instances are objects that's share the same object data. In other words, you can't make different instances, because they just the same. Take a look at <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> copies. They are linked, they are instances of the same data, and if you change one of them - the second will be changed also.

Instead of making the building and when distribute it on the surface, do the opposite thing: distribute the root thing on the surface and then add walls and windows on every root thing at the same time.

There is another way: make several buildings models, put them into one collection and instance them using this collection